# Save function dataframe values to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

I have a function that creates a dataframe:

```
def function(date):
...
return dataframe
```

Now I want to put the dataframe values into a dictionary with the key being the date and the dataframe being the value:

```
d = {}
d[date] = dataframe
```

however, every time I rerun the function to add a new date, it adds the new date and value but it also overrides the previous date's value. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. From what you've written it's impossible to say *what's* currently happening, let alone *why*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are keying your dictionary by dates, they must be unique to avoid overwriting the existing value for a given date.

Alternatively, you could create a list of values for a date using something like this:

```
d = {}
try:
    d[date].append(dataframe)
except KeyError:
    d[date] = [dataframe]
```

This uses Python's [EAFP coding style](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) to attempt to append a dataframe to a list of dataframes for a given date.  If an exception is raised because the dictionary doesn't contain the date-key, it then creates a key of the given date and assigns it a single-item list value which can later be appended to.

Answer (score 0):

From the minimal information that was given, I can only assume that you're putting a dictionary inside a for loop. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2]], columns = ['A'])

for date in ['2017-02-27','2017-02-28']:
    d = {}
    d[date] = df
```

This will return a dictionary that only contains data for '2017-02-28' because the dictionary is being overwritten each iteration of the for loop.